Swagger can't seem to reference model when using examples (multiple example)
How do i reference my models when trying to use multiple example using model/DTO?
@ApiExtraModels(DeliveryOrderListOkDTO, DeliveryOrderListOk2DTO)
@ApiOkResponse({
  content: {
    'application/json': {
      examples: {
        exampleOne: {
          $ref: getSchemaPath(DeliveryOrderListOkDTO),
        },
        exampleTwo: {
          $ref: getSchemaPath(DeliveryOrderListOk2DTO),
        },
        exampleThree: {
          value: {
            message: 'Works fine without ref',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
// ...


Output:



Generated Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0 Schema:


How am i suppose to use the $ref variable from the source code?:


This question is similar to: How can I display multiple ResponseDTOs' schemas in Swagger/NestJS?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
